# How to get all unread items using Feedly API

Tags: api, feedly

OK, either this is incredibly obvious and I'm just too dumb to see it, or it is not possible at all.

I created a [Feedly developer access token](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/developer/) and can call some end points just fine, like /profile, /categories, etc. Currently testing them with curl, but eventually will do this in Ruby.

What I can't find from the documentation (or even by Googling) is how to access all the unread entries from all my subscriptions just like I do in the Feedly app:

[image: Feedly All Unread Items]

As far as I understand, Streams are for specific feeds. And the closest thing to the All stream, I *think*, is the [Global Resource Id](https://developer.feedly.com/cloud/) "global.all". But when I call it according to the documentation I get "API handler not found".

```
curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth [<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>]' http://cloud.feedly.com/v3/user/<MY_USER_ID>/category/global.all

{"errorCode":404,"errorId":"ap5int-sv2.2018082612.1607238","errorMessage":"API handler not found"}
```

At some point I thought maybe Feedly just doesn't support this and went and looked at Inoreader's API documentation and [it looks pretty much the same](http://www.inoreader.com/developers/). There is no /All stream where I can pull my unread entries. So I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

What I am trying to do:

Basically I want to create an app for myself where I pull all my unread entries and flag the ones I'm interested in as "Read Later". This is part of a bigger workflow app that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. To get a stream of all your unread articles, the syntax would be:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access token>' 'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/<user id>/category/global.all&unreadOnly=true'
```

> The `<user id>` can be obtained by the `Profile` API which can be found [here](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/profile/).

The streams API is documented [here](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/streams/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: That was it! Thank you thank you thank you! You have no idea how many hours I spent trying to find this!

Comment: @david which api give this streamId ?

Comment: @Sam there's not really an API. Most developers build these stream ids in code (the user id is returned by the [profile](https://developers.feedly.com/v3/profile) API).

Comment: But this still fetches the items themselves. And if there are more than 20 items, you need to fetch next pages, etc. Isn't there a simple API function in feedly that simply shows item count, without fetching items?

Comment: @Maximko If you just need the ids, you can use `/v3/streams/ids` instead of contents (it also allows you to fetch up to 500 ids in a single call). If you just want the unread count, then you can use the [counts API](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/markers/#get-the-list-of-unread-counts) instead.